# C++; Accepting User Input Only if it matches a preset pattern

Tags: c++

G'day everyone.

I'm very new to C++ and just sort of playing around with some small scale stuff to get the hang of the basics. I want to create a program that will take user input from cin, and print it out if, and only if, it matches a preset template, for example LLL000 (so, 3 letters followed by 3 numbers). Think of something like a gym membership, where the user ID follows the 3 letter and 3 number format.

This is the code I came up with so far

```
//User ID checking
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;


int main()
{
    string letter;
    int number;

    std::cout << "Enter your ID: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> letter;
    std::cin >> number;

    if (letter.size() <= 0 && letter.size() > 3)
    {
        std::cout << "There must be 3 letters!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else if (number < 99 || number >= 1000)
    {
        std::cout << "The number has to be between 100 and 999";
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Your ID is " << letter << number;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

My problems are that:

1. Line 15-25 doesn't seem to do what I thought it would do. In fact, it seems to me like it completely ignores that line when the program runs
2. If line 21 were to work as I thought it would, it would also mark a user id like 005 as invalid. I don't know how to get it to fill in that gap with 0s.
3. The code doesn't actually have anything that would try to compare to some sort of format, since I have no idea how to do that.

I apologize if this is something incredibly easy that I'm just not seeing, and appreciate any help!

I'd also like to add that I noticed that string will also accept numbers, and not just letters as input, which I didn't know could happen.

Comment: If you cout an integer it prints the integer. It doesn't print the zeros. Also your code isn't correct for the question you are solving.

Comment: It's impossible for a number to ever be below 99 and above 1000.

Comment: If you wanted 3 letters why didn't you equate letter.size() and 3? And since strings can have numbers try s[i] >='a' && s[i] <= 'z'

Comment: why don't you use a regex?

Answer (score 0):

For comparing strings, or portions of strings, you want to use the [compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) method of the STL string class in C++. This allows you to compare one `std::string` against another or compare it against a substring of another.

```
  std::string str1 ("blue fruit");
  std::string str2 ("red fruit");

  if (str1.compare(6,5,"fruit") == 0)
    std::cout << "still, " << str1 << " is a fruit\n";
```

The first parameter is a `size_t` position while the second is the amount of characters you want to compare. You can also simply just put in one parameter, another string, to compare the whole string against each other.

**Check for a numerical digit**

If your interested in checking if a char is a 0-9 digit for example, use the [isdigit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) method from the C portion of the STL.